# How to solve definite integral with an upper bounds of pi?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm not sure how to do this definite integral:

$$\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt[6]{\pi}}\ x^5\cos x^6\,dx$$

$u = \cos x$, is that correct?

$du = -\sin x \space dx$

I'm not sure how to handle the $x^5$

=== **Update** ===
$$ u = x^6  $$
$$ du = 6x^5dx  $$
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt[6]{\pi}}\ \frac{1}{6}\cos(u)du$$
$$\frac{1}{6}sin({(\sqrt[6]{\pi}})^6) - \frac{1}{6}\sin({(0})^6) = 0 $$

Comment: Your calculus are ok. But you can do it in another way. I wrote you an answer.

Comment: I bet you meant $\int\limits_0^{\sqrt[6]\pi} \frac16 \cos(u) \space du = [\frac16\sin u]_0^{\sqrt[6]\pi}$ but everything else checks out and looks fine.

Comment: @craz1001 If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\int f'(x)\cos(f(x))\,dx=\sin(f(x)) + c$ you get:
$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt[6]{\pi}}\ x^5\cos x^6\,dx= \frac 16 \int_{0}^{\sqrt[6]{\pi}}\ 6x^5\cos x^6\,dx=\frac 16 \left[\sin(x^6)\right]_0^{\sqrt[6]{\pi}}=\frac {\sin(\pi)-\sin(0)}6=0$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT

Let’s try with:

$$u=x^6$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Observe that $\;\int f'(x)\cos(f(x))\,dx=\sin(f(x)) + C\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

That looks like  $\cos {(x^6)}$, not $\cos^6 x$ or $(\cos x)^6$. $u= \cos x$ won't work here. You're gonna have to use the substitution $u = x^6$.

Answer (score 0):

No, $u= \cos(x)$ is not appropriate because you don't **have** $\cos(x)$!  You have $\cos(x^6)$.  That $x^5$ should have been clue as to what to do with the "$x^6$" in"$\cos(x^6)$". The first thing you should do is use the substitution $y= x^6$. Then $dy= 6x^5dx$, $x^5= \frac{1}{6}dy$.  When $x= 0$, $y= 0^6= 0$. When $x= \sqrt[6]{\pi}$, $y= (\sqrt[6]{\pi})^6= \pi$.  The integral becomes $\frac{1}{6}\int\limits_0^\pi \cos(y)dy$